# Multiple contact numbers of the same person : which number has been used

Tags: contacts, sms

If a person in my contacts has more than one phone number and when he/she calls , the call log just shows all the numbers. How to figure out which number he/she used to call. (SMS as well)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tap the details to bring up the contact -- if you swipe across to the history, you'll see things like:

> 1 missed call
> Mobile, Thu
>
> 1 missed call
> Home, Tue
>
> 1 call
> Mobile, 17/01

Which then tells you which contact number they used to get hold of you.